# Installed ubuntu alongside Windows 8, interface is very small

Tags: dual-boot, resolution

Here is a picture of the problem: [http://imgur.com/ID2NKnG](https://imgur.com/ID2NKnG)

I have had this problem before on windows after I had it plugged into the TV via HDMI. When I unplugged it the same thing happened (where everything was very small) but it went back to normal after I restarted the computer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Select the lower resolution. System settings -> Displays

Comment: Is this the only way? I don't really want to run the computer on a lower resolution because it obviously looks considerably worse. On Windows I have it on the same resolution (3200x1800) and don't have the same problem. Is there an option for global scaling or something?

Comment: then look at the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Under the settings icon on the launcher (gear), you can select universal access and turn on "large text".  Then under the settings appearence icon select the Look tab, and there is a slider at the bottom to increase the size of the launcher icons.

---

At high resolutions, individual programs may offer text size options, like Firefox, under edit/preferences/content select text size, and under the advanced button, more font size options, like not allowing the page to override the font selection.  Unfortunately, many web designers don't have a clue about user font size changes, so their pages will look pretty scrambled.

Comment: This did help with the icons on the left of the screen, but the text within programs (eg. firefox) is still very small. This is how it still looks: [http://i.imgur.com/ZLXmJdo.png]